# nodejs to mosquitto raspberry pi pub sub not work

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, mosquitto

Hi I am trying to sub and pub to mosquitto service runing on raspberry pi using Nodejs on my windows 10 but no thing happen on Rpi console
here is my code

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.10.97');

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence');
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

so my raspberry pi with ip 192.168.10.97
however when II test the commend from raspberry pi console it work secsussfully

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t "iot"

mosquitto_pub -d -t "iot" -m "Hi, This is my msg..."
```

so what is the problem ?
thank you

Comment: Check your router and windows firewall to make sure port 1833 (or whatever ports you've configured for mqtt if not standard) is allowed.

Comment: You're trying to make 2 MQTT clients (`mosquitto_pub/sub` and Node `mqtt`) talk with each other. You have to run an MQTT Broker [like Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html) in the background for them to communicate. Consequently `mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.10.97')` this should be the address of your Broker, and not the other client.

Comment: @AlexisFacques the fact the mosquitto_pub/sub command work on the pi imply that there is a broker running there.

Comment: ok for raspberry pi there is an mosqutto broker instelled an i try to pub sub to that broker
now How can i check if there is a firewall in my windows 10 or check the 1883 pot

Comment: I am confused  why  i need to check the port on windows but in my case the server is on raspberry pi not windows @AlexisFacques

Comment: @Nacer_dz You may want to check to which address/interface the Mosquitto broker is binded to. Run the following command on your RPi : `sudo netstat -pant | grep 1883` (if 1883 is the port is listening to). This should return you something as such `XX.XX.XX.XX:1883`. Anything else than `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) is not good. I suspect Mosquitto to be only listening on loopback, as you're able to pub/sub locally, but not remotely.

Comment: that's the result
tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:1883   0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN
2209/mosquitto 
tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57092    TIME_WAIT
tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57128    TIME_WAIT
tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57153    TIME_WAIT
.....

Comment: that's the result
`code 
    tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:1883   0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN
    2209/mosquitto 
    tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57092    TIME_WAIT
    tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57128    TIME_WAIT
    tcp  0   0 192.168.10.97:1883  192.168.10.99:57153    TIME_WAIT
    .....`

Comment: now why i can't pub sub from nodejs if there is a connection

Comment: are you see my answer Mr.@AlexisFacques ?

Comment: @Nacer_dz, did you find any solution for this? I am also stuck into this one.