# why publish from paho raspberry pi to Mosca node js give me an error?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I am trying to sub and publish from Paho library running on my raspberry pi to MOSCA MQTT broker on my nodejs server running on windows machine but no thing happen 
so what is the problem 
Note: when i connect to the broker from nodejs client it works 
here is my nodejs code

```
var mosca = require('mosca');

var settings = {
  port: 1883
};

//here we start mosca
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
}

// fired whena  client is connected
server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published : ', packet.payload);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting
server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected
server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});

// this is my client request

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.10.99:1883');

client.subscribe('presence');

console.log('Client publishing.. ');
client.publish('presence', 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());

client.end();
```

and here is my python code running on my raspberry pi

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
broker="192.168.10.99"
#define callback
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("received message =",str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

client= paho.Client("client-001") #create client object client1.on_publish = on_publish #assign function to callback client1.connect(broker,port) #establish connection client1.publish("house/bulb1","on")
######Bind function to callback
client.on_message=on_message
#####
print("connecting to broker ",broker)
client.connect(broker)#connect
client.loop_start() #start loop to process received messages
print("subscribing ")
client.subscribe("house/bulb1")#subscribe
time.sleep(2)
print("publishing ")
client.publish("house/bulb1","on")#publish
time.sleep(4)
client.disconnect() #disconnect
client.loop_stop() #stop loop
```

My python error is :

```
sudo python clientpaho.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clientpaho.py", line 40, in <module>
    mqttc.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1481, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1003, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1284, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1849, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2311, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2372, in _handle_connack
    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Is this the same 2 machines as in your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076889/nodejs-to-mosquitto-raspberry-pi-pub-sub-not-work)? If so it really does imply it is some network/firewall related issue.

Comment: yes what do you mean network/firewall on raspberry pi or windows machine

Comment: no idea without access to both, but I would guess the Windows machine as normally Raspbian doesn't have any firewall enabled

Comment: I edit my question what about the error @hardillb

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is My solved problems:

Paho client doesn't connect to nodejs ==> disable firewall on windows

error caused by **on_connect** function it need 4 parameters not 3 parameters like this `on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)`

thank you